# skips "if" statement in certain inputs

Tags: c++, if-statement

So i have done a program that encrypts input in the way Julius Ceasar did (adding to all letters a constant number).

The program seems to work fine until it reaches the z + 6 barrier, at which point it start to dismiss the if statement that will make the alphabet circular.

I just can't understand why it will stop working when it reaches that point.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char encoded(char c, int k) {
    k %= 26; //too big numbers!
    c += k; //encrypt
    if (c > 'z')
        c = c-'z'+ 'a' -1; //circular alphabet
    c = c - 'a' +'A'; //uppercase
    return c;
}

int main () {
    int k;
    while (cin >> k) {
        char c;
        while (cin >> c and c != '.') {
            if ('a' <= c and c <= 'z') 
                cout << encoded(c,k);
            else if (c == '_') 
                cout << ' ';
            else 
                cout << c;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

If someone can give me a clue on what is going on I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "reaches the `z + 6` barrier". In particular, what is the input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: Note that `'z' + 'a' - 1` and `'a' + 'A'` can be simplified, which might help you debug your code.

Comment: It might be an overflow issue. Try using `unsigned char`.

Comment: Try looking at the ASCII encoding of uppercase and lowercase letters. Then trace through your code on paper for a few values.

Comment: The value of the end of the lowercase alphabet (like 'z') is close to the maximum value which can be held in a (signed) char variable.  I suspect that `c += k` may be overflowing.

Comment: You should use a debugger and execute each statement one at a time.  *Watch* the values in the variables to verify they are within range and correct.

Comment: Write unit tests first then write code. Be sure to test border conditions ('A', 'Z', 'a', 'z' ±1, min char, max char etc...). The write your code and fix it until all tests pass. **Seriously, it should not be hard to add a `cout` in `encoded` and test it by calling `encoded('z' + 6, 10)`** and understand your problem in much less time that it take to write the question!

Comment: In my opinion, your question is poorly written because `'z' + 6` is ambiguous. Without analysis, it is hard to tell if your program give wrong output if `c` is not in the range `a` to `z` (lowercase) or ok the value of `k` is >= 6 or both… Also, it is not clear if input should be restricted to a-z or works for the whole character range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you get an overflow. Datatype `char` probably ranges from -128 to 127 (architecture dependent). The ASCII code of 'z' is 122, so 122 + 6 is not 128, it is-128.

You can solve it:

```
char encoded(char c, int k) {
    const int len = 'z'+1-'a';
    int ch = (int)c + k%len; //encrypt
    if (ch > 'z')
        ch = ch - len; //circular alphabet
    ch = ch - 'a' +'A'; //uppercase
    return (char)ch;
}
```

I would prefer this solution:
Convert your character to a number from 0 to less than 26 encode it and convert it back to a character.

```
char encoded(char c, int k) {
    const int len = 'z'+1-'a';
    if ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' )
        c = (c-'a' + k) % len + 'A'; // + 'A' because of toupper ( +'a' keep lower)
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is poorly written. One has to read the whole code to see that you are calling the function only for letters between `a` and `z`.

It seems very suspicious that you would convert encrypted letters to uppercase but won'.t encrypt letters that were already uppercase.

It is a very poor design to check range inside `main` (except for the stop condition) and not inside `encoded` function. If at some point, you realize that you were supposed to convert uppercase letters too, then you have to modify both `main` and `encoded` functions.

Also, it make the function `encoded` hard to reuse as you always need to do a bunch of `if` before calling it.

So this is pseudo-code for what you should do in your `encoded` function:

- If letter is lower case, then make it uppercase first (so that uppercase letter in input would be encoded too).
- If the letter is an uppercase letter, then do the rotation appropriately (already explained in details in other answer and comments; you just need to remove the uppercase conversion).
- If the letter is `_` then replace it by a space
- Otherwise, returns the characters as it.
- Remove from your `main` function and test inside the `while` statement block.

For readability, it might be a good idea to have a `make_upper` function and maybe even a `rotate(char ch, int k)` function.

**One of the reason, I do not provide code is because it is probably an homework and you have to put some efforts in it.**